# Generate Safe SQL In JavaCode

Tags: java, mysql

How to compose SQL(MySQL) like PreparedStatement, such as escaping, to avoid SQL injection and genearte safe SQL statement.

Is there any present JavaCode to do this?

Real scenario:
Frontend input as column value to compose a safe SQL (the "where" part), the specified in the backend are table name and column name.

Comment: Yes, by using prepared statements. You cannot generate a "safe sql statement" that you can *then* fill with parameters, that does not exist. You need a safe way to generate the filled sql which is what PreparedStatement does.

Comment: use JDBC template and give a parameter in this to avoid SQL injection

Comment: JDBC template can be used only when connected to a DB Server. What expected is one can be used without connection to DB Server, or the "Static Method" .

Comment: @JackMa Please [edit] your question to include a detailed description why prepared statements is not an option for you.

Answer (score 1):

There are some SQL builders, and in general they keep track of all parameters and build a PreparedStatement. It might even be an idea to not only provide parameter values, but parameter names, so one may use it as a real PreparedStatement.

You may create a JdbcTemplate from Spring. Or Criteria API.

If you want to build your own, as research, you might explore escaping too.

Then (research) also consider barring Unicode bidi hacking with LTR (`\u200E`) and RTL (`\u200F`): by using a Right-To-Left control one can obfuscate the SQL looking seemingly okay in the editor, but doing something maliciously different. You could require that the characters may not appear in a string but must be escaped too: `\\u200F`. *(However it is something for nerds or insiders, and your SQL must already be at a sensitive spot.)*

The SQL dialect is important; backtick (MySQL) or double quotes (Standard) for names etcetera.

There is Apache's commonlang **[`escapeSql`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html#escapeSql(java.lang.String))**.

Comment: Thanks, firstly. JdbcTemplate or Criteria API is useful only when connected to a DB server, namely, initiated with some real db connection info. What expected here is some Util can be used directly without the initiation by db connection info.

Comment: JPA (eclipseLink, hibernate) with criteria API relies on on modelling on an existing database for autocompletable table and column names, but JPA also allows to create a database from entity classes. But probably you want something with table and column names as Strings - guaranteeing correct SQL syntax only?

Comment: By the way that is a valid and useful requirement too.

Comment: Thanks firstly. But some times there is no DB server. All the elements required to build SQL are passed from the front-end.